# xUnit test, how to implement fact unit test for specific method

Tags: c#, .net-core, c#-7.1

I would like to know how I can implement a unit test for this method

```
private void ConfigLogging(IConfigurationRoot configuration)
{
    var nLogConfigFile = Path.Combine(configuration["environment:root"], "configs", configuration["application:configDirectory"], configuration["application:id"] + "_NLog.config");

    if (File.Exists(nLogConfigFile))
    {
        LogManager.Configuration = new LoggingConfiguration();
        LogManager.LoadConfiguration(nLogConfigFile);
    }
    else
    {
        var logFilePath = Path.Combine(configuration["environment:root"], "logs", configuration["application:logDirectory"], configuration["application:id"] + ".log");
        var loggingConfiguration = new LoggingConfiguration();

        var logFile = new FileTarget("logfile")
        {
            FileName = logFilePath,
            Layout = new SimpleLayout("${longdate}|${appdomain}-${assembly-version}|${pad:padding=5:inner=${level:uppercase=true}}|Job: ${pad:padding=8:inner=${var:JobId}}|Thread: ${threadid}|${pad:padding=25:inner=${logger:shortName=true}}|${message} ${when:when=length('${exception}')>0:inner=[Exception=${exception}]}${newline:when=length('${exception}')>0}${exception:format=toString,Data:maxInnerExceptionLevel=10:exceptionDataSeparator=\r\n}"),
            Footer = new SimpleLayout("${longdate}|${appdomain}-${assembly-version}|=====Application stopped====="),
            ArchiveNumbering = ArchiveNumberingMode.Date,
            ArchiveEvery = FileArchivePeriod.Day
        };

        loggingConfiguration.AddRule(NLog.LogLevel.Info, NLog.LogLevel.Fatal, logFile);
        LogManager.Configuration = loggingConfiguration;
    }

    LogManager.KeepVariablesOnReload = true;
    if (!LogManager.Configuration.Variables.ContainsKey("JobId"))
    {
        LogManager.Configuration.Variables.Add("JobId", new SimpleLayout(string.Empty));
    }

#if DEBUG
    var debugOutput = new OutputDebugStringTarget("debugoutput");
    LogManager.Configuration.AddRule(NLog.LogLevel.Trace, NLog.LogLevel.Fatal, debugOutput);
    LogManager.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
#endif
}
```

Comment: What do you want to test?

Comment: I want to test LoadConfiguration if exist the nLogConfigFile with all the condition